# XCOPY Batch file to backup on weekly bases & based on current day i.e monday,tuesday..etc

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, remote-backup

```
@ECHO OFF

C:\DOS\XSET DAY DAYOFWEEK
IF NOT "%DAY%" == "1" GOTO END

:BACKUP
C:\DOS\XSET CUR-DATE DATE YY-MM-DD
IF EXIST C:\BACKUP\%CUR-DATE%.ZIP GOTO FILE
C:\UTIL\PKZIP\PKZIP C:\BACKUP\%CUR-DATE%.ZIP C:\DATA\*.*

XCOPY C:\Users\Admin\Downloads*.ZIP /DB#7 /RSY /PD0 /ED
GOTO END

:FILE
ECHO.
ECHO    %CUR-DATE%.ZIP File Already Exists!
ECHO      No Additional Backup Performed.
ECHO.

:END
SET DAY=
SET CUR-DATE=
```

Hi
This is my above code
I want to create an automatic backup based on day
For Example today is Monday if i am running a backup script it should take last Monday backup & also check the date of last monday. Then it should overwrite the data in folder called Monday
I will be creating each folder each in a week i.e. for Tuesday folder name Tuesday will be created, for Wednesday a folder name Wednesday will be created

Comment: It looks like you are using `XXcopy` as `Xcopy` does not have those switches.  XXcopy may have switches to create the day of week folder.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try yarcgui which is a gui for robocopy and will make your task much easyier:  http://yarcgui.wilkes.es ?